# Change the order of the images

Tags: product, configurable-product, catalog, image, csv

Does anyone know if it is possible to change the order of the images already imported through a CSV template?

Example this is the loaded order

[image]

I want to alternate it by this order

[image]

I appreciate the help for this issue

Comment: have you installed any third-party extensions? for product related?

Comment: no, at this time I do not have any third party extensions installed for related products.

Comment: hello, dear first you can try Magento cache: flush and cache: clean and reindex commands after that not working then share your CSV file. I will check in detail.